# Django foreignkey, retrieving the value

Tags: django

I was trying get the value from a `ForeignKey` but it throws a type error.  Please give me a solution.

```
class LenderInvestment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    investment = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, default=1000000)
    initial_capital = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, **optional)
    date_stamp = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.initial_capital)


class LoanDisbursement(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    initial_capital = models.ForeignKey(LenderInvestment, **optional)
    loan_applicant = models.ForeignKey(LoanApplication)
    money_disbursed = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    pay_slip = models.FileField(_('Upload depostited payslip'), upload_to=upload_location2,
                            storage=FileSystemStorage(location=settings.PROTECTED_ROOT))
    date_stamp = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.user)

def loan_disbursement_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    initial_capital = instance.initial_capital[0]
    money_disbursed = instance.money_disbursed
    initial_capital -= Decimal(money_disbursed)
    instance.initial_capital = initial_capital

pre_save.connect(loan_disbursement_receiver, sender=LoanDisbursement)
```

The error says indexing not allowed; how I can take the first index value of the `initial_capital`? Thank you in advance.

Comment: That makes no sense. `initial_capital` is a foreign key, it only has one value.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I want to do some calculation using pre_save signals. Suppose if I do investment = instance.investment
    initial_capital = Decimal(investment) * Decimal(0.2)
    instance.initial_capital = initial_capital

Comment: Hi Daniel, I want to do some calculation using pre_save signals. Suppose if I do investment = instance.investment
    initial_capital = Decimal(investment) * Decimal(0.2)
    instance.initial_capital = initial_capital, it is giving the error     "raise TypeError("Cannot convert %r to Decimal" % value)
TypeError: Cannot convert <LenderInvestment: 20000.00> to Decimal" how it can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Your `pre_save` is connected to the `LoanDisbursement` model which has a foreign key to `LenderInvestment` model. The problem is that the foreign key field can only one value - a link to the `LenderInvestment` model object. So. instead of

```
initial_capital = instance.initial_capital[0]
```

try to do

```
initial_capital = instance.initial_capital
```

since it is the only right way to get the connected object.

Comment: Hi Adilet Maratov, removed the indexing and tried a calculation as mentioned above but throws error: r("Cannot convert %r to Decimal" % value) TypeError: Cannot convert <LenderInvestment: 20000.00> to Decimal" how it can be solved?

Comment: instead of `initial_capital = instance.initial_capital` do `initial_capital = instance.initial_capital.initial_capital` and it should work

Comment: Cannot assign "Decimal('400.0000000000000083266726847')": "LoanDisbursement.initial_capital" must be a "LenderInvestment" instance.

Comment: when i write initial_capital = instance.LenderInvestment.initial_capital it gives AttributeError at /api/disbursement/add
'LoanDisbursement' object has no attribute 'LenderInvestment'.

Comment: It is expected to get AttributeError, because your LoanDisbursement class does not have LenderInvestment attribute. It has foreign key to it, which lives in initial_capital attribute. Take time and learn Python please.